# How to retrieve the content of a IFormFile when uploading to onedrive's user using microsoft api

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, microsoft-graph-api, batch-request

I do have some problems when uploading files with Batch Request of Microsoft graph API. My file and folder will upload but when i try to open the file, i have an error and i can't see the content of this file.
Here what I did so far :

```
        public async Task BatchUploadFileAsync(string DriveID, GetAllFilesToUpload filesToUpload)
        {

            int batchSize = 20;

            var batchesOfFiles = new List<List<FileDatatoUpload>>();
            var currentBatch = new List<FileDatatoUpload>();

            foreach (var file in filesToUpload.Files)
            {
                currentBatch.Add(new FileDatatoUpload
                {
                    FormFile = file.FormFile,
                    Folder = file.Folder,
                    TypeOfDocument = file.TypeOfDocument,
                    SchoolYear = file.SchoolYear,
                    Curriculum = file.Curriculum,
                    Language = file.Language,
                    Semestre = file.Semestre,
                    PathStudent = file.PathStudent,
                    AcademicYear = file.AcademicYear,
                    Student = file.Student
                });

                if (currentBatch.Count == batchSize)
                {
                    batchesOfFiles.Add(currentBatch);
                    currentBatch = new List<FileDatatoUpload>();
                }
            }

            if (currentBatch.Count > 0)
            {
                batchesOfFiles.Add(currentBatch);
                currentBatch = new List<FileDatatoUpload>();
            }

            var batchRequestContent = new BatchRequestContent();

            try
            {

                // Parcourez chaque lot de fichiers
                foreach (var batchFiles in batchesOfFiles)
                {
                    foreach(var file in batchFiles)
                    {
                        // Lecture du contenu du fichier
                        using (var fileStream = file.FormFile.OpenReadStream())
                        {

                            byte[] fileBytes = new byte[fileStream.Length];
                            fileStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);

                            string fileBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);
                            var jsonObject = new
                            {
                                contentBytes = fileBase64
                            };

                            // Sérialisation en JSON
                            string jsonContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObject);

                            // Création de StringContent à partir du JSON
                            var stringContent = new StringContent(jsonContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                            // Création de la requête de chargement
                            var request = _graphServiceClientApp.Users["userId"].Drive.Root
                                .ItemWithPath(Path.Combine(file.PathStudent))
                                .Content.Request().GetHttpRequestMessage();

                            request.Method = HttpMethod.Put;
                            request.Content = stringContent;

                            // Ajout de la requête de chargement au batch
                            batchRequestContent.AddBatchRequestStep(request);


                        }

                        batchSize++;

                        // Envoyer la demande batch lorsque la taille maximale est atteinte
                        if (batchSize == 20)
                        {
                            await _graphServiceClientApp.Batch.Request().PostAsync(batchRequestContent);

                            // Réinitialiser la demande batch pour le prochain groupe de fichiers
                            batchRequestContent = new BatchRequestContent();
                            batchSize = 0;
                        }

                    }
                    if (batchSize > 0)
                    {
                        await _graphServiceClientApp.Batch.Request().PostAsync(batchRequestContent);

                        // Réinitialiser la demande batch pour le prochain groupe de fichiers
                        batchSize = 0;
                    }



                }

            }
            catch (ServiceException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error uploading: {ex.ToString()}");
            }

        }
```

I did try to use MemoryStream and some others things just after file.FormFile.OpenReadStream() but it does the same things, no files and folder or just the folder and the file but no content.
I did check on the net to see if someone have the same problem but i didn't see any answer that could help me resolve my problem.
Can please someone help me or give me advice on what i do wrong ?
Thank you very much :)

Comment: `byte[] fileBytes = new byte[fileStream.Length];` <-- This is unnecessary, you can stream data without buffering it all into-memory.

Comment: `fileStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);` <-- This might be the cause of some problems: you **need to** check the return value from `Read` and call `Read` in a loop until all data is read (i.e. when `Read(...)` returns `0`)

Comment: `string fileBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);` <-- _oh god why_ are you doing this? Base64 encoding is not appropriate for moving large binaries (i.e. files sized more than a few kilobytes).

Comment: OneDrive's web-service documentation shows how they support proper binary uploads of files with `PUT` requests, see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_put_content?view=odsp-graph-online - there is no need to use JSON, Base64, or other horrible anti-pattern techniques that too many people seem to be using today for some reason.

Comment: OneDrive also supports multiple-file-uploads using `multipart` requests: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_post_content?view=odsp-graph-online

Comment: @Dai  I just took an example from my collegue and since i am not really confortable with this i didn't change it for most part but it's sure that my files are not large and i can't use multipart since i'm not uploading in my personnal drive.
I'lk leep check and return to you after searching a bit ! ty !

Comment: ah it's mb, i misunderstood the part "Multipart upload is only available on OneDrive personal"

Comment: Ah, whoops - I need to apologize for that then. I missed that line in the doc page I linked to, sorry.

Comment: it's okay, i'll try with the hint you gave me  :)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, i did some change in my code

```
public async Task BatchUploadFileAsync(string DriveID, GetAllFilesToUpload filesToUpload)
    {
        int batchSize = 20;

        var batchesOfFiles = new List<List<FileDatatoUpload>>();
        var currentBatch = new List<FileDatatoUpload>();

        foreach (var file in filesToUpload.Files)
        {
            currentBatch.Add(file);

            if (currentBatch.Count == batchSize)
            {
                batchesOfFiles.Add(currentBatch);
                currentBatch = new List<FileDatatoUpload>();
            }
        }

        if (currentBatch.Count > 0)
        {
            batchesOfFiles.Add(currentBatch);
            currentBatch = new List<FileDatatoUpload>();
        }

        try
        {

            List<System.IO.Stream> streams = new List<System.IO.Stream>();

            foreach (var batchFiles in batchesOfFiles)
            {
                var batchRequestContent = new BatchRequestContent();
                foreach (var file in batchFiles)
                {
                    // Créer et ouvrir le stream
                    var fileStream = file.FormFile.OpenReadStream();

                    var fileToWrite = System.IO.File.Create("D:yourFileName.pdf");

                    // This will copy the content of your fileStream to fileToWrite
                    fileStream.CopyTo(fileToWrite);

                    // Ensure that all data has been flushed to the disk and close the file
                    fileToWrite.Close();

                    // Ajouter le stream à la liste
                    streams.Add(fileStream);

                    Console.WriteLine($"Uploading file {file.FormFile.FileName} to {file.PathStudent}");

                    //using (var fileStream = file.FormFile.OpenReadStream())
                    //{
                    string encodedPath = Uri.EscapeDataString(file.PathStudent);

                    var request = _graphServiceClientApp.Users["userId"].Drive.Root
                            .ItemWithPath(Path.Combine(encodedPath))
                            .Content.Request().GetHttpRequestMessage();

                        request.Method = HttpMethod.Put;
                        request.Content = new StreamContent(fileStream);
                        request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");

                    Console.WriteLine($"Request URI: {request.RequestUri}");

                    // Add upload request to batch
                    batchRequestContent.AddBatchRequestStep(request);
                    //}
                }

                // Send the batch request
                var response = await _graphServiceClientApp.Batch.Request().PostAsync(batchRequestContent);
                Console.WriteLine($"Response status code: {response.GetResponsesAsync().Status}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Response content: {response.GetResponsesAsync().Result.Values}");


            }

            // Fermer tous les streams
            foreach (var stream in streams)
            {
                stream.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (ServiceException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error uploading: {ex.ToString()}");
        }
    }
```

I did try to check on my filestream as well and it seems fine, but i found an error i didn't see that could help me advance a little

Request URI: [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/emailId/drive/root:/E-Portfolio%2FAcadémique%2F1113254-RDNSemester-2020-2021-PGE3A-EN-S2.pdf:/content](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/emailId/drive/root:/E-Portfolio%2FAcad%C3%A9mique%2F1113254-RDNSemester-2020-2021-PGE3A-EN-S2.pdf:/content)

and the error i am getting :

```
Error uploading: Status Code: 0
```

Microsoft.Graph.ClientException: Code: invalidRequest
Message: Unable to deserialize content.

---> System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException: '%' is an invalid start of a value. LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.

Comment: this is not an answer, it is a question.